# How can I use next-redux-wrapper with redux-toolkit without typescript

Tags: redux, next.js, redux-toolkit, next-redux-wrapper

I'm In trouble With Making a new `nextjs` app using `redux-toolkit` with `next-redux-wrapper` and all methods I found is explain using `typescript` So Please Help Me if you can

I want to Make an Application Use Using `Nextjs` , `Redux-toolkit` and `next-redux-wrapper` without using typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always copy TypeScript code examples into https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99 and it will show you the JavaScript code. Generally, TypeScript is just JavaScript with a little bit of extra, so many tutorials only show TS nowadays.